# Get solution of an lineal ordinary differential equation without constants

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I made an algorithm for solving an specific IVP. I get the solution with the function `dsolve()` in MatLab, but I don't want to get the solution in terms of the constants because I'm gonna replace the solution in my IVP.

For example, when I solve `dsolve('Dy = x + y','x) '` I get `C12*exp(x) - x - 1` but I only want to obtain `exp(x) - x - 1`. It's very straightforward to chop out the `C12` by converting the sym to string, but I don't know if I try with a different function will it have more constants and only 'chopping' the first characters will work. So...

Is there a way to get the output of `dsolve()` without the constants?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add an initial condition and you'll have an output without constants.
Like dsolve('Dy = x + y','y(0)=0','x')